# Is it possible to prevent git from immediately removing the reflog of deleted branches?

Tags: git

`git branch -d <branch>` deletes the branch and also it's reflog (in `.git/logs/refs/heads/<branch>`). Yes, you can probably recover the branch from `HEAD`'s reflog, but why throw away the branch's reflog immediately? Surely it would be more sensible to keep it around and gc it later. This would also give a much easier way to undelete branches (no hunting through `HEAD`'s reflog).

1. Is this is a good idea?
2. Assuming the answer to 1 isn't "no, it's a horrible idea", can this be achieved by config options (I didn't find any) or by some combination of plumbing commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad idea, and the reflog entries will go away on their own after the usual expiration, so I'm not sure why `git branch -d` deletes the reflogs.

I verified that `git update-ref -d` does *not* delete the reflog, so yes, you can achieve the desired affect through plumbing commands.  Write whatever tests you like before invoking `git update-ref`, then use `-d` to delete if the tests pass.

Comment: I stumbled upon a [mailing list thread](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/150734) about this, turns out there are some corner cases involving naming conflicts of dead branches. I might use this anyway, for my personal use I can just avoid name conflicts.

Comment: Interesting, I guess that explains why no one has done it yet (handling the technical issues would obviously be annoying to code up).